# Batch script with tasklist

Tags: batch-file

I use this

```
tasklist /S testpc /FI "IMAGENAME eq NomadBranch.exe"| find /I /N "NomadBranch.exe"
```

to check if a process is running on a remote computer. But I use a batch script and sometimes the tasklist ask for a password. I don't see that when I turned echo off.

How can I skip the login for a user when asked. I need to check a lot of computers and I don't want a username and password in the batch script for security reasons

Feedback is welcome !

Comment: I suppose it asks for password when you execute this against a remote machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Administrator rights to the remote computer, then only you will may not need to specify a Username and Password.

Comment: I have administrator right. But some XP computers are not working good and don't give me access. Some user have local administrator right and change settings. But the system is asking then for a username and password. Nomather what I give up I dont have access. I need to skip this and i can't keep a eye on the batch when it checks 1000 pc's.